# Saving data from Java interface to SQLite database

Tags: java, sqlite

I've managed to program a Java interface to display records from a SQLite database. I've been following these tutorials:

http://freevideolectures.com/Course/3555/Java-Eclipse-GUI/13

I've got the following code on a button to save data that's been entered into text boxes but whenever I click the button it comes back with "Query does not return results". I'm not sure if this has something to do with the fact I'm not putting data into all of the fields within the table (the missing three are from check boxes so I'm not sure how to include them).

I was wondering if maybe someone could check my code, Java doesn't throw up any errors but the SQL must not be quite right. I've checked the field names and they're definitely not the problem.

```
            JButton btnSaveData = new JButton("Save S1 data");
            btnSaveData.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    try {
                        String query="insert into S1Pupils (Forename, Surname, YearGroup, RegSet, PracticalSet, Behaviour, Medical, Barriers, Strategies, CurrentInfo, Assessment, LastUpdated) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                        PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);
                        pst.setString(1,txtForename.getText());
                        pst.setString(2,txtSurname.getText());
                        pst.setString(3,txtYearGroup.getText());
                        pst.setString(4,txtRegSet.getText());
                        pst.setString(5,txtPracticalSet.getText());
                        pst.setString(6,txtBehaviour.getText());
                        pst.setString(7,txtMedical.getText());
                        pst.setString(8,txtBarriers.getText());
                        pst.setString(9,txtStrategies.getText());
                        pst.setString(10,txtLastUpdate.getText());
                        pst.setString(11,txtAssessment.getText());
                        pst.setString(12,txtLastUpdated.getText());
                        pst.executeQuery();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data saved");
                        pst.close();
                    } catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Should be set String 1 2 3 4 5 6 7... Instead of 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Comment: Oh blast so it should, thank you!

Comment: I've made the changes to 1,2,3 etc. but it's still giving me the same error. :-(

Comment: executeQuery is for **select** queries. Use executeUpdate(), or execute().

Comment: That's sorted it out JB Nizet, thank you!